# Export obj from Blender keeping position

Tags: export

I'm trying to model some things for Poser.  Whenever I export the .obj out of Blender it ends up on the floor in Poser.  I'd like it to keep its position.

Comment: Where is the origin of the obj? Poser likely places the origin at the center of the scene, so make sure the origin is at the center of the blender scene before exporting (Ctrl+A and apply location should do the trick).

Comment: That still brings it into Poser on the floor.  :/

Comment: Post some screenshots and a as-simple-as-possible blend file that shows the problem.

Comment: http://anniemation.com/blender1.jpg

Comment: http://anniemation.com/blender2.jpg

Comment: See how the glasses are on the head of the model in Blender?  But when I export them to poser they end up on the floor.

Comment: I got it figured out.  Needed to un tick the centered in Poser import.